# Get value from a JavaScript array.object using id number

Tags: javascript

Based on the `var data` below.  How can I get the `full_name` value if all I have is the number `2`?  Number 2 corresponds with `id: 2` and the full_name would be `Eric`

```
var data = [{
                id: 0,
                full_name: 'None',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 1,
                full_name: 'John',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                full_name: 'Eric',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                full_name: 'Larry',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                full_name: 'Rick',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 5,
                full_name: 'John',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 6,
                full_name: 'Eric',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 7,
                full_name: 'Larry',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 8,
                full_name: 'Rick',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 9,
                full_name: 'John',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 10,
                full_name: 'Eric',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 11,
                full_name: 'Larry',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }, {
                id: 12,
                full_name: 'Rick',
                gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
            }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(data.filter(function(x) { return x.id == 2 })[0] || {}).full_name;
// => "Eric"
```

`data.filter` will return only elements that fit the given criterion; in this case, `id` being `2`. Since we only care about one element, we will just take the first found element; but if none exist, `.full_name` will give an error about `full_name` not being defined on `undefined`, so we put in an empty object just in case the search fails using `|| {}`.

Comment: Your answer is great but I just realized I made a mistake.  Basically I have a selection using Select2 library and it returns the number 0-13 based on the selected item.  Because my ID matches the array numbers, I mistaken it.  So in reality I need to take a returned number and simply match it to the array item and then get the ID for that array/object item.  Could you help with that as well please?

Comment: Then it is trivial: `data[id].full_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Amadan's answer most probably is better/more failure proof than mine, but if you know that your array of objects will always contain objects from Id 0 to Id infinite, you could also get it with

```
var wanted = data[number].fullName
```

Comment: I just realized this as my question was backwards and the array key number is actually what my selection was returning to me but since it matched my ID I didnt realize it.  IN real production the ID will be different but the code I am using is returning the array key from selected item on a change event so this is actually what I need!

Comment: then amadan's answer will be the right for you. @torazaburo thanks for the edit. One of my first answers in good English now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

ES6 offers [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), to find the first element in an array that meets some condition:

```
var wanted = data.find(elt => elt.id === 2);
```

If you don't have this available, there are various polyfills, including one on the page referenced above.

Comment: I'm just in reading progress for node js. Can I transform your code via babel too node directly?

Comment: You can use `babel-node`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myQuery(array, id){
    for(i in array){
        if(array[i].id === id){
            console.log(data[i].full_name);
            return data[i].full_name;
        }
    }
}

myQuery(data, 2)
```

If you are keeping your ID equal to the place in the array, you could just do this.

```
function myQuery(id){
    return array[id].full_name
}
```